# Why retrofit2 add slash at end of URL?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

i'm working on app that fetch posts from my wordpress website using retrofit2 , in my interface i have this method to get author avatar

```
@GET("user/get_userinfo" + &insecure=cool)
Call<CallbackAuthorAvatar> getAuthorAvatar(
        @Query("user_id") int id
);
```

after implement, the URL will be something like this   "http://mywebsite.org/api/user/get_userinfo/?user_id=1&insecure=cool/"

this not working because the slash at end of URL

Question how can i remove that slash ?

My RestAdapter

```
public class RestAdapter {
public static API createAPI() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return false;
        }
    }).create();

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.addInterceptor(logging);


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();


    return retrofit.create(API.class);
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the code where you define your base url

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast i have post answer with my RestAdapter

Comment: Are you getting the same error if you decide to use another @Query parameter for the "insicure" key? `Call<CallbackAuthorAvatar> getAuthorAvatar(@Query("user_id") int id, @Query("insicure") String parameter);`

Comment: @nicopasso yes not working

Comment: what is BASE_URL? please add